# Why is there no apply(x: String, xs: String*): Array[String] overloading in scala.Array Companion object?

Tags: arrays, scala, factory-method, companion-object

```
val arrayInt = Array(1, 2)
```

gets transformed into a factory method

```
Array.apply(1, 2)
```

that works since there is an apply(x: Int, xs: Int*): Array[Int] overloading in [scala.Array Companion object](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#apply(x:Int,xs:Int*):Array[Int]).

However, there is no apply(x: String, xs: String*): Array[String] overloading in that.
How can

```
val arrayStr = Array("aa", "bb")
```

work?

Comment: It uses the generic one https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array$.html#apply[T](xs:T*)(implicitevidence$5:scala.reflect.ClassTag[T]):Array[T]